# How to change csv files encoding from [ANSI] to [UTF-8] by batch

Tags: r, tidyverse

There is file list as below,

```
"2022-01-07.csv" 
"2022-01-11.csv"
 "2022-01-14.csv"
 "2022-01-21.csv" 
"2022-02-08.csv" 
"2022-02-17.csv" 
"2022-02-21.csv"
```

They are stored in encoding 'ANSI', how can i change them to 'UTF-8' by batch? Thanks!

Comment: Try looping over the files, reading and writing them with the `stringi` package. Specifically [stri_read_lines()](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/rapi/stri_read_lines.html) and [stri_write_lines()](https://stringi.gagolewski.com/rapi/stri_write_lines.html), where you can specify the input and output encoding easily.